# Equivalent to regexp_replace((^[A-Z])|([IJ])|(?<= ).) in regexp_substr

Tags: sql, db2, regexp-replace, regexp-substr

In DB2, the next query works fine:

```
select  REGEXP_REPLACE( 'René de la Ömer-Arie IJsbrand IJsse'
                      ,'(^[A-Z])|([IJ])|(?<= ).','') FROM "SYSIBM".SYSDUMMY1
```

Result: `ené e a mer-Arie sbrand sse`

However, I would like to achieve the opposite result:

```
RdlÖIJIJ
```

If I try the regexp_substr equivalent, it doesn't give me the desired outcome:

```
select  REGEXP_SUBSTR( 'René de la Ömer-Arie IJsbrand IJsse'
                  ,'(^[A-Z])|([IJ])|(?<= ).') FROM "SYSIBM".SYSDUMMY1
```

Result: `R`

Is there a way to achieve the result "RdlÖIJIJ" with (or without) regexp_substr?

Comment: Which edition of DB2: luw, i, z?

Comment: @TheImpaler DB2 iSeries / AS400.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could match a char other than `I` or `J` while asserting a non whitespace char to the left, and replace with an empty string.

```
(?<=\S)[^IJ]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QEAvG6/1)